# DPDT Switch Configuration

Tags: led, circuit-design, switches

How can I wire a DPDT switch with color-changing LED inside so that the green LED lights up when the switch is pressed and the red LED lights up when the switch is not pressed?

When you switch the polarity between the led pins the colour changes.
[image: Pin Out]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect LED pins to C1 and C2. NO1 to NC2 and NC1 to NO2. Power to either NC1 and NC2 or NO1 or NO2. Polarity of PS not known because you did not mention how the LED color defined.

Comment: Wow, I was just over complicating things. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

Here's the wiring diagram.

[image]

And the schematic.

[image]